# Power BI(DAX): All() not working only for 2 values of the column

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have created a `[A]` which calculates the organic balance for the prior year-end. Now, I'm creating a copy of `[A]` `[B]` which will calculate the overall balance by selecting three values from `[Column1]` column(ignoring any filter applied to/by the column). The values are "C", "D" & "F".

The formula of `[A]`

```
A = 

var _date = MAX('Date-Table'[Date])
var _month = MONTH(_date)

var _prior_year_date = if(_month=1,EOMONTH(_date,-13),EOMONTH(_date,-_month))
var _prior_year_end_organic_balance = CALCULATE([Organic Balance],FILTER(ALL('Date-Table'),[Date]=_prior_year_date))

return _prior_year_end_organic_balance
```

The formula of `[B]`

```
B = CALCULATE([A],FILTER(ALL('Table'[Column1]),'Table'[Column1]="D" ||'Table'[Column1]="F" || 'Table'[Column1]="C"))
```

Values in `'Table'[Column1]`
|Column1|
|-|
|A|
|B|
|C|
|D|
|E|
|F|

measure `[B]` is showing correct and same value for values "A","C","E" & "F", but the value is changing for "B" & "D".

Can anyone please help me understand why the value is getting altered for "B" & "D"?

Comment: Using a single column argument, ALL returns all the unique values of the column.  Are there duplicate values that would affect your output?

Comment: Values in Column1 are getting repeated. Also, In visual, I'm displaying the value of measure B against [Column2] of 'Table2', and there is no relation between 'Table1' and 'Table2', is it possible that Power BI is creating a cross-join between both the columns, so I'm getting wrong values?